# Interrupt triggering type (edge-triggered vs level-sensitive) mismatch

Tags: arm, interrupt-handling, armv8

I'm writing a small OS on ARMv8 architecture with GICv3.

During device initialization, I expected an interrupt to be taken to the OS. However, it's never triggered. And it turned out I misconfigured the interrupt triggering type of the device as "level-sensitive" even though the actual interrupt triggering type is "edge-triggered". After changing the interrupt triggering type to "edge-triggered", I was able to receive the interrupt of the device.

Here's my question:

- How GIC receives and forwards the asserted interrupts depends on the interrupt triggering type?
- According to how GIC works (receive and forward), why was the interrupt never triggered with my wrong configuration?
- What happens if I misconfigured the interrupt triggering type in the opposite way? (If I misconfigure the interrupt triggering type as "edge-triggered" but the actual one should be "level-sensitive".)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

An interrupt, in general, is just the assertion of a signal line.  When the interrupt condition is present, the line is asserted; when not present the line is de-asserted.

The thing listening to a line, an interrupt controller, can interpret the signal in two ways:  by transition or state.  By transition means that the controller *remembers* it asserting itself, and retains that memory until some action is taken to *clear* that memory.  By state means that the controller merely reflects the state of the signal line.

Transition, or *Edge* permits a simpler hardware controller, that can merely assert pulses indicate a change of state, whether it be *carrier detected* or *character received*.  In a state or *Level* controller, a simple thing like *carrier detected* becomes a cumbersome multi-state exchange between the controller and the CPU.

State, or *Level*, however permits a hardware controller to insist upon attention until the underlying condition is satisfied.  This is not just convenient when a single interrupt signal is shared by multiple devices, but to avoid a race between the hardware controller and the CPU.  In general, *Edge* oriented devices need to be re-examined after processing an interrupt, to ensure the squelching of the interrupt controller didn't miss an interrupt pulse.

So, when you set the mode in something like a GIC, you need to know how the hardware device behaves, and program the GIC correspondingly.  It isn't a selection of how you would like the device to behave; rather it is a configuration of how the device does behave.   Mercifully, device-tree gives you that information, and if you can't believe device tree, then all is lost.